# Screen Adjustment based upon websites

Tags: screen, resolution

Is there anyway to adjust screen resolution based upon the websites ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying whether you want to adjust the resolution of the users of your website, or if you want to adjust your own based on the websites you visit.

The former: **Don't.**

The latter: I guess, theoretically, there could be a program that would do that, but I can also guess that any such program would be a pain to develop, so I wouldn't hold my breath. In my opinion, the best way to achieve what you're after is to set your resolution high enough for all sites, and then either resize your browser window, or use a per-site zoom setting.